# Moving development of Android app to new machine

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android application that was programmed using Eclipse as the editor on one laptop. When I exported/published/signed the application to create the .apk, I did so on this machine, creating a new keystore in a folder on the C drive.

I want to move development to a new laptop. I already have the SDK, Eclipse, etc, etc moved over to the new laptop, including the project core files. Is it okay to move the keystore to the new machine and put it in the same directory? Does anything else have to be done in order to use this same keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, each time you sign and package, it will ask you (or it will remember your last choice) where your keystore is. I would say copy it over, when you first attempt to sign / package it will ask where it is at, and you can select it.

Answer (score 2):

The keystore does not depend on a particular computer, so you are safe to do this.